# NW.js / NodeJS Google Analytics integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, google-analytics, node-webkit

I tried to implementing google analytics API in a node-webkit application with [Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide), I managed to do that with ga-dev-tools.appspot.com but I can't use it with a simple javascript request.
I suppose the problem was the header parameter "Origin" (in a node-webkit app is "file://"), therefore I tried to use a http request with node but I reached the same result: google respond with `"hitParsingResult": [ {"valid": true,...` however in Google Analytics Dashboard ? can't see the event or, in this case, a pageview.

The strange thing is that if I copy the request with chrome inspector on the 
ga-dev-tools.appspot.com (copy as cURL) and I exec it in the linux terminal it works but not with nodejs http request.

The details:
cURL call

```
curl 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/' -H 'Origin: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data 'v=1&t=screenview&tid=UA-XXXXX-X&cid=develop&an=mainapplication&av=2.0.1&cd=login'
```

nodejs code

```
request.post("https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect", 

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36',
            'Origin': 'https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com',
            'Referer': 'https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/',
            'Accept': '*/*'
        },
        formData: 'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-X&cid=develop&an=mainapplication&av=2.0.1&t=screenview&cd=login'
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
        else
        {
            console.error(error)
        }
    })
```

I tried to find a nodejs module to do that but I can't find one with Application integration (screenview, an, av..)

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curl request is going to `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect` and your Node.js request is going to `https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect` (notice the `debug` in the URL).

The debug endpoint is for debugging errors only. It does not send actual hits to Google Analytics. I suspect that's your problem.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow :) by the way, if an answer helps you solve a problem, you should upvote it and/or mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved all my issues and posted the code on github, if someone needed it:
[nwjs-analytics](https://github.com/Daaru00/nwjs-analytics)

Comment: Great - thanks for that; just what I was looking for.